# linking of devise gem and rapidfire gem with application.html.erb common properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rapidfire-gem

I am trying to implement Rapidfire Gem in my application which include Devise Gem for Login process. All goes well, but the problem occurs when I trying to set layout of Edit and logout through Application.html.erb file.

The ERROR is shown of

> NameError in Rapidfire::QuestionGroups#index'

on Rapidfire's index page

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the root cause should be that there are no [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) routes available in the engine by definition. You have to connect it first.

There's a discussion over here on how to do that: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2827